# Rails 3.1 really weird issues happening randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on some Rails 3.1 medium-sized app and am currently having some weird issues happening randomly **after I start a local server**.

It happens really often after the start of the server, and most of the times, if not every time, it's about an undefined method **which is actually defined**.

If I then put some *binding.pry* or *debugger* just before the line making the app crash and I try to **use myself that method I get the expected result** (no crash). And if I leave the debugging console the server just goes back to normal.

For instance I get :

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `type=' for #<Publication:0xb398f180>):
  app/controllers/publications_controller.rb:115:in `new' ``

If I go the that controller and add *binding.pry*

```
@publication = current_user.publications.new
binding.pry
@publication.type = type
```

hit refresh, type this in the console

```
Publication.new.type = PublicationType.first
```

and then leave the console the server just goes back to normal.

This seems to be only happening in my local environment. I never encountered such an issue after deploying to production nor when running specs.

Since I'm the only one it's not that bad but soon other devs will be working on the code base so it's gonna be an actual problem.

**EDIT :**

I ran into this other error today :

```
undefined method `color_class' for #<Publication:0xb39e44f0>
```

from

```
= link_to truncate(comment.publication.title, :length => 30), comment.publication, :class => "category-font #{comment.publication.color_class}"
```

then I just did the binding.pry trick and typed

```
comment.publication.color_class
```

then left the console and everything went fine ...

**EDIT 2 :**

Ok now it gets even more weird ...

I ran into the same issue as above, the color_class one. Except this time the trick described doesn't work, see pry output :

```
     3:     = link_to publication_path(comment.publication, :anchor => "comment-#{comment.id}") do
     4:       = link_to comment_excerpt(comment), comment_link(comment), :class => "comment_excerpt"
     5:       \-
     6:       = link_to comment.author.username, comment.author
     7:       \-
 =>  8:       - binding.pry
     9:       = link_to truncate(comment.publication.title, :length => 30), 

    comment.publication, :class => "category-font #{comment.publication.color_class}"
    [1] pry(#>)> comment.publication.color_class
    NoMethodError: undefined method `color_class' for #
    from /home/jerefrer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
    [2] pry(#>)> comment.publication.category
    NoMethodError: undefined method `category' for #
    from /home/jerefrer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
    [3] pry(#>)> comment.publication.id
    => 139
    [4] pry(#>)> comment.publication == Publication.find(139)
    => false
    [5] pry(#>)> Publication.find(139).color_class
    => "some-class"
```

And I can't seem to find any trick this time ... just keep getting the same error ...

**EDIT 3 :**

And a new one !

```
> Comment.includes(:publication => :author).order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
Hirb Error: Association named 'author' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
> Comment.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
[is working]
> Comment.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).first.author
[is working]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Assuming `Publication` is an `ActiveRecord` model, you should not be using `type` except as part of Single Table Inheritance. Are you?

Comment: @Chowlett 
Actually I have publication belongs_to :type, :foreign_key => "publication_type_id", :class_name => "PublicationType".
I made this just out of convenience, but will try to use publication_type everywhere to see if it prevents this issue.

Anyway I'm running into a similar issue (see post edit) but not related to this "type" field.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Single Table Inheritance, or type is just a column you defined? If this is the case, be aware that activerecord thinks by default that the type column is to specify the name of the subclass in a hierarchy relationship, so if you are not implementing that there could be conflicts.
If you really wanted that attribute to be called type, you should overwrite Base.inheritance_column

More info: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html (Single table inheritance section)

Comment: I tried not overriding "type" by using "publication_type" everywhere and the error still remains ...